# Clicking on Push Notification is Not opening the push activity -Using IBM Mobile First

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing native android app and integrating IBM MobileFirst.

I have scenario where I have to push the notification to notification tray irrespective of app in fore ground or background.

In my manifest I have declared the following activity

```
<activity android:name=".controllers.activities.pushActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="${applicationId}.sample.NOTIFICATION"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

So what I did was I have set the **WlPush.setForeground** to always **false**. So that when ever push comes it goes to the notification tray on click of which, will open the push activity. This is working completely fine except for one scenario.

When app is  killed and we receive a push notification and click on it opens the app.. While the app is still in the foreground and app receives a push again this time the push comes to the notification tray but on click of the notification the push activity is never called.

But this works completely fine when open the app by clicking on the app icon from home.

Any one had seen an issue like this before.

Regards.